# How can I start a conversation only once even if it's starting inside Update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemAction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public camMouseLook mouselook;
    public GameObject lockedRoomCamera;
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public GameObject navi;
    public ConversationTrigger trigger;
    public GameObject player;

    private Vector3 playerposition;
    private Quaternion playerrotation;

    private bool torotate = false;

    public void Init()
    {
        navi.transform.parent = null;
        navi.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        navi.transform.LookAt(lockedRoomCamera.transform);
        PlayerController.disablePlayerController = true;
        mouselook.enabled = false;
        playerCamera.enabled = false;
        lockedRoomCamera.SetActive(true);
        torotate = true;

        playerposition = player.transform.position;
        playerrotation = player.transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(torotate == true)
        {
            RotateRandom.RandomRotation(navi.transform);
            PlayConversations.ConversationToPlay(3);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's calling this line many times :

```
PlayConversations.ConversationToPlay(3);
```

I don't mind it will be called many times but I want it to play for exmaple index 3 only once. If it started playing the index remember it started playing and played the index in this case 3 and don't play it again even if it will call this line in the Update over again.

This is the PlayConversations script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayConversations : MonoBehaviour
{

    private static ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;
    private static PlayConversations instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        conversationTrigger = GetComponent<ConversationTrigger>();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static void ConversationToPlay(int index)
    {
        ConversationTrigger.conversationsToPlay.Add(index);
        instance.StartCoroutine(conversationTrigger.PlayConversations());

    }
}
```

And the ConversationTrigger script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditorInternal;

public class ConversationTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();
    public static List<int> conversationsToPlay = new List<int>();

    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject canvas;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool conversationEnd;
    [HideInInspector]
    public static int conversationIndex;

    private DialogueManager dialoguemanager;

    private void Start()
    {
        conversationIndex = 0;
        dialoguemanager = FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>();
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayConversations()
    {
        conversationEnd = false;
        var conversations = conversationsToPlay.ToArray(); // Copy the list
        conversationsToPlay.Clear(); // Immediately clear the original list

        for (int i = 0; i < conversations.Length; i++) // iterate over the array
        {
            // Now you also don't need to remove items anymore, 
            // since you already cleared the list
            yield return StartCoroutine(PlayConversation(conversations[i]));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayConversation(int index)
    {
        if (conversations.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[index].Dialogues.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < conversations[index].Dialogues.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dialoguemanager != null)
                {
                    dialoguemanager.StartDialogue(conversations[index].Dialogues[i]);
                }

                while (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == false)
                {
                    yield return null;
                }
            }

            conversationIndex = index;
            conversationEnd = true;
            canvas.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("Conversation Ended");
        }
    }

    public void SaveConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(conversations.ToArray(), true);
        File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json.txt", jsonTransform);
    }

    public void LoadConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json.txt");
        conversations.Clear();
        conversations.AddRange(JsonHelper.FromJson<Conversation>(jsonTransform));
    }
}
```

Either to make inside the PlayConversations script or inside the ConversationTrigger that when it started playing a conversation don't play this conversation over again.

The problem is that each place in the game I'm playing a conversation like in this case I need to use flags to make it stop after start playing but inthis case for example while the conversation is playing I'm also rotating an object and that should be in the Update and be called many times :

```
RotateRandom.RandomRotation(navi.transform);
```

But the conversation should start only once.

Since I don't see a reason why to play the same conversation twice in the game then I want it to be playing only once without the need to use flags each place.

Comment: Why you should call starting in update ?? maybe you can make a callback in PlayConversations , don't use "conversationEnd" flag to check end

Comment: @TimChang Do you mean why I'm calling the PlayConversations.ConversationToPlay(3); inside the Update ? Because I wanted the conversation to be played while the object is rotating at the same time. And when the conversation is ended to stop the rotation. So now I removed the conversationEnd flag as you suggested.  But now ho do I make for example what I want in the example with the object rotation ?